# Двойное срабатывание addEventListener в javscript

Tags: javascript

```
function startGame() {
    // const circlesList = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')
    board.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if ( event.target.classList.contains('circle') )
        {
            alert (gameCounter)
            let element = event.target.getAttribute('data-num')
            console.log (':', gameCounter, element)
            if ( gameCounter == element){
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
                scoreCount.innerText = ++score

                // if (gameCounter == circlesCount) {
                // console.log ('+', gameCounter, element)
                gameCounter++
                if ( circlesCount - gameCounter == 0) {
                    console.log ('goood', gameCounter, circlesCount)
                    board.innerHTML = ''
                    circlesCount = circlesCount + 1
                    gameCounter = 0
                    createCircle(circlesCount)
                } 

            }else {
                // console.log ('-', gameCounter, element)
                // event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            }
            
        }        
    })
      
}
```

В этом участке, после 1й итерации, по нажатию на круг  addEventListener (а может и не он) срабатывает n раз , где n это текущая итерация. alert замечательно это демонстрирует!

Смысл игры в том что бы последовательно повторять появления кружков нажимая на них.

Протестировать можно здесь https://jsfiddle.net/ctacua/0w7tmrgd/1/

Comment: Вы вешаете обработчик нажатия в функцию, которая вызывается каждый раз, как начинается новый уровень. Соответственно на каждом новом уровне создается новый обработчик, а те, которые существовали -- никуда не деваются. Вынесите назначение обработчика в глобальную область, а функцию `startGame` просто уберите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы решить проблему сходу, код листнера вынесете в функцию, тогда можно будет слушатель удалять. Данное поведение обусловлено тем, что вы каждый раз добавляете новый слушатель, не удаляя предыдущий.

Однако лучший вариант, это посмотреть, где и как вы вызываете функцию `startGame`. Ее необходимо вызывать только один раз при запуске, что бы не заниматься постоянной установкой и удалением слушателей.

```
function listner(event) {
    if ( event.target.classList.contains('circle') )
        {
            alert (gameCounter)
            let element = event.target.getAttribute('data-num')
            console.log (':', gameCounter, element)
            if ( gameCounter == element){
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
                scoreCount.innerText = ++score

                // if (gameCounter == circlesCount) {
                // console.log ('+', gameCounter, element)
                gameCounter++
                if ( circlesCount - gameCounter == 0) {
                    console.log ('goood', gameCounter, circlesCount)
                    board.innerHTML = ''
                    circlesCount = circlesCount + 1
                    gameCounter = 0
                    createCircle(circlesCount)
                } 

            }else {
                // console.log ('-', gameCounter, element)
                // event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            }
            
        }  
}

function startGame() {
    // const circlesList = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')
    board.removeEventListener('click', listner);
    board.addEventListener('click', listner);
      
}
```

Comment: Да, точно, что то я забыл это дописать... Поправил

Answer (score 0):

у тебя при каждом попадании на круг вызывается alert, он считает gameCounter, а так как он у тебя повышается при каждом попадании, следовательно и вызывается n-попаданий раз.

Comment: АЛЕРТ всего лишь индикатор. Убрав его это не решит проблему.

Comment: значит я глупый, просто через алерт неудобно же, каждый раз закрывать его придется, чтобы дальше на кружочк клачать

Comment: алерт это дебаг, который в отличае от консоль.лог показал мне проблему наглядней!